# Weird Date MySQL INSERT statement (vb.net app but MYSQL command)

Tags: mysql

I've got a really random bug in my code somewhere but can't figure it out.  I'm inserting data into a MySQL Database based the current date and use the following statement;

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL,495297,str_to_date('19/01/2013 10:55:25','%d/%m/%y'),'English - UK',1,Str_to_date('17/01/2013','%d/%m/%y'),str_to_date('18/01/2013','%d/%m/%y'))
```

none of the dates work as the 19/01/2013 for some reason it becomes 19/01/2020, the next become 17/01/2020 and 18/01/2020!  The latter two dates are listed as Date in data Type whereas the first date is DateTime so I don't know why this bizarre problem is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Maudise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capital `%Y` as identifier for the year:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (NULL,495297,str_to_date('19/01/2013 10:55:25','%d/%m/%Y'),'English - UK',1,Str_to_date('17/01/2013','%d/%m/%Y'),str_to_date('18/01/2013','%d/%m/%Y'))
```

The lower case `%y` specifies a year given by two digits (see MySQL documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)). The uper-case `%Y`, however, is the four-digit version.